# Testcontainers: communication between containers + mapped outside port

Tags: java, docker, testing, integration-testing, testcontainers

I have such test setup:

1. `MyService` connects to `PostgtreSQL`
2. `MyService` endpoint is being called from test suite

Both `MyService` and `PostgreSQL` are being run with Testcontainers.

Here is the network schema I want to achieve.

[image: Network Schema]

At first I tried to arrange communication by exposing ports.

```java
static final PostgreSQLContainer<?> postgres =
            new PostgreSQLContainer<>(DockerImageName.parse(POSTGRES_VERSION));

static final GenericContainer<?> myService = new GenericContainer<>(DockerImageName.parse(MY_SERVICE_IMAGE))
                .withEnv(
                    Map.of(
                        "SPRING_DATASOURCE_URL", postgres.getJdbcUrl(),
                        "SPRING_DATASOURCE_USERNAME", postgres.getUsername(),
                        "SPRING_DATASOURCE_PASSWORD", postgres.getPassword()
                    )
                )
                .withExposedPorts(8080)
                .withLogConsumer(new Slf4jLogConsumer(LoggerFactory.getLogger("MyService")))
```

According to logs `MyService` couldn't establish connection to `PostgreSQL`.

```
Caused by: java.net.ConnectException: Connection refused
```

Then I configured both services to share the same network.

```java
static final Network SHARED_NETWORK = Network.newNetwork();

static final PostgreSQLContainer<?> postgres =
            new PostgreSQLContainer<>(DockerImageName.parse(POSTGRES_VERSION))
                 .withNetwork(SHARED_NETWORK)
                 .withNetworkAliases("postgres");

static final GenericContainer<?> myService = new GenericContainer<>(DockerImageName.parse(MY_SERVICE_IMAGE))
                .withEnv(
                    Map.of(
                        "SPRING_DATASOURCE_URL", "jdbc:postgresql://postgres:5432/" + postgres.getDatabaseName(),
                        "SPRING_DATASOURCE_USERNAME", postgres.getUsername(),
                        "SPRING_DATASOURCE_PASSWORD", postgres.getPassword()
                    )
                )
                .withExposedPorts(8080)
                .withNetwork(SHARED_NETWORK)
                .withNetworkAliases("MyService")
                .withLogConsumer(new Slf4jLogConsumer(LoggerFactory.getLogger("MyService")))
```

Now `MyService` has established connection with `PostgreSQL` successfully. But when I perform HTTP request to `MyService` from the test suite, I get the same error.

```java
restTemplate.getForObject("http://" + myService.getHost() + ":" + myService.getMappedPort(8080) +"/api/endpoint", Void.class)
```

```
Caused by: java.net.ConnectException: Connection refused
```

My question is how can I setup the containers network to make this architecture work?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to specify port bindings to expose a port to the "outside world".

Example similar to what you want:

```
  Network network = Network.newNetwork();
  GenericContainer mariaDbServer = getMariaDbContainer(network);
  GenericContainer flywayRunner = getFlywayContainer(network);
  ...
  @SuppressWarnings("rawtypes")
  private GenericContainer getMariaDbContainer(Network network) {

    return new GenericContainer<>("mariadb:10.4.21-focal")
        .withEnv(Map.of("MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD", "password", "MYSQL_DATABASE", "somedatabase"))
        .withCommand(
            "mysqld", "--default-authentication-plugin=mysql_native_password", "--character-set-server=utf8mb4",
            "--collation-server=utf8mb4_unicode_ci").withNetwork(network).withNetworkAliases("somedatabasedb")
        .withNetworkMode(network.getId())
        .withExposedPorts(3306).withCreateContainerCmdModifier(
            cmd -> cmd.withNetworkMode(network.getId()).withHostConfig(
                    new HostConfig()
                        .withPortBindings(new PortBinding(Ports.Binding.bindPort(20306), new ExposedPort(3306))))
                .withNetworkMode(network.getId())).withStartupTimeout(Duration.ofMinutes(2L));
  }

  @SuppressWarnings("rawtypes")
  private GenericContainer getFlywayContainer(Network network) {

    return new GenericContainer<>("flyway/flyway:7.15.0-alpine")
        .withEnv(Map.of("MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD", "password", "MYSQL_DATABASE", "somedatabase"))
        .withCommand(
            "-url=jdbc:mariadb://somedatabasedb -schemas=somedatabase-user=root -password=password -connectRetries=300 migrate")
        .withFileSystemBind(Paths.get(".", "infrastructure/database/schema").toAbsolutePath().toString(),
            "/flyway/sql", BindMode.READ_ONLY).withNetwork(network).waitingFor(
            Wait.forLogMessage(".*Successfully applied.*", 1)
        ).withStartupTimeout(Duration.of(60, ChronoUnit.SECONDS));
  }
```

Container two communicates with container one using "internal" port.

Container one exposes 20306 (that redirects to 3306) port to the "outside world".

Comment: Does that mean that port `20306` must be always free? If so, it might be a problem. For example, there can be two simultaneous builds in CI environment. Is it possible to expose random port?

Comment: Yes. port 20306 must be available. You can use another port (random or not) if you inject it to both apps. If you CI is using docker images (ex: gitlab) to perform the build that is not a problem.

Answer (score 1):

The docker custom network has its own DNS and you cannot use DNS of the outer network. The default host network shares DNS of the outer and inner networks, but has some disadvantages. To connect a database container to a service container you can use `--network-alias` that docker converts to ip (https://docs.docker.com/get-started/07_multi_container/ ). For example:

```
 postgres = new PostgreSQLContainer<>("postgres:15")
            .withDatabaseName("cars")
            .withUsername("cars")
            .withPassword("cars")
            .withNetwork(network)
            .withNetworkAliases(“database”)
            .withLogConsumer(new Slf4jLogConsumer(log));
    postgres.start(); 

carsModelsService = new GenericContainer<>("cars/car-models-service-core:latest")
            .withExposedPorts(8180)
            .withNetwork(network)
            .withEnv("POSTGRES_HOST", “database”)
            .dependsOn(postgres)
            .withLogConsumer(new Slf4jLogConsumer(log));
    carsModelsService.start();
```

where:

application.yml

```
spring:
  datasource:
    driver-class-name: org.postgresql.Driver
    url: jdbc:postgresql://${POSTGRES_HOST}:5432/cars
    username: cars
    password: cars
```